# laravel i need add values to table in database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i need to add Task_id from My Form  to task_id in database  This Code in the controller is working fine but i need it To add id value withput deleting old one  like

if task_id in the database have  (3)
and the Task id from the form is (8) it should be (3,8)

but My controller delete (3) and put (,8)

i need it to be in this format to expload it later 
      public function store(){

```
    Enrollee::where('path_id',1 )->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id )->update([
    'user_id'  => auth()->user()->id ,
    'task_id'  => ','.request('Task_id')

]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing that because you're overwriting the `task_id` variable, simply fix by doing so:

```
public function store(){

    $enrollee = Enrollee::where('path_id',1)->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first()

    Enrollee::where('path_id',1 )->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id )->update([
        'user_id'  => auth()->user()->id,
        'task_id'  => $enrollee->task_id.','.request('Task_id')
    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
store(){

    $oldTasks = Enrollee::where([['path_id', '=', 1],['user_id','=',Auth::user()->id])->first();

    Enrollee::where('path_id',1 )->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id )->update([
    'user_id'  => auth()->user()->id ,
    'task_id'  => $oldTasks.','.request('Task_id')

]);
```